# Big performance loss with NodeJS loops on Amazon EC2 server

Tags: node.js, loops, optimization, amazon-ec2, v8

I am running a Amazon EC2 M1 General Purpose Small (1 core x 1 unit) 64 bit instance.

I've established that the Amazon instance is on average about half as fast as the computer I'm working on when using a **single-threaded** `nodejs` app:

```
var time = Date.now();

var fibo = function(n) {
  return n == 0 ? 0 :
         n == 1 ? 1 :
         fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2);
};

console.log("fibo(40) = " + fibo(40));

time = Date.now() - time;
console.log("Took: " + time + " ms");
```

**localhost:**
`fibo(40) = 102334155`
`Took:` **1447** `ms`

**Amazon EC2:**
`fibo(40) = 102334155`
`Took:` **3148** `ms`

Now when in my bigger app I iterate over a big 5MB JSON object (5MB being the formatted and indented filesize, I assume this is smaller internally) using 6 nested `for` loops (and for the sake of argument please assume with me that this is necessary) I end up with about 9.000.000 iterations.

On **localhost**, this takes about **8 seconds**. On **Amazon EC2**, this takes about **46 seconds**.

I expected this to be 20 seconds at most.

**What causes Amazon to lag so much more?**

I know V8 is highly optimized.

**Is `javascript`/`V8`/`node.js` perhaps using optimizations that aren't compatible with virtual machines (like the EC2 instance)?**

And similarly

**Any special kind of code optimizations recommended for crazy stuff like this?**